# Amazon S3 object with special characters throws error?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am using the https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class for store and retrive the objects.Its working fine if the objects contains the normal name without special characters.But if the object contains the [] character(Like [test].jpg I tested only for this ) and if I am using the getobject method it will throws an error NoSuchakey.

If I get  the S3 URL directly and  paste into the browser I can download the image.

But I want to use getobject method.So how to avoid this error.I don't want to change the original object name.

**Edit:**

PHP Version 5.2.6

Comment: Are you forgetting to apply [URL encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)?

Comment: $rest = new S3Request('GET', $bucket, $uri) here where I need to apply URL Encode?

Comment: nvm, it already does it for you with `rawurlencode($uri)`

Answer (score 1):

I see this note in the comments for [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) on php.net:

> phpversion()>=5.3 will compliant with RFC 3986, while
>   phpversion()<=5.2.7RC1 is not compliant with RFC 3986.
>
> History of related RFCs:
>
> RFC 1738 section 2.2  only alphanumerics, the special characters
>   "$-_.+!*'(),", and  reserved characters used for their reserved
>   purposes may be used  unencoded within a URL.
>
> RFC 2396 section 2.3  unreserved  = alphanum | mark  mark        = "-"
>   | "_" | "." | "!" | "~" | "*" | "'" | "(" | ")"
>
> RFC 2732 section 3  (3) Add "[" and "]" to the set of 'reserved'
>   characters:
>
> RFC 3986 section 2.3  unreserved = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" /
>   "~"
>
> RFC 3987 section 2.2  unreserved = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" /
>   "~"

The following code produces the same output on 5.3.2 and 5.2.15 though:

```
<? echo rawurlencode ("[hello]") . "\n\n"; ?>
%5Bhello%5D
```

Can you try creating a copy of `S3.php` and changing `S3Request` to modify the `$this->url`:

```
$this->uri = $uri !== '' ? '/'.str_replace('%2F', '/', rawurlencode($uri)) : '/';
$this->url = str_replace("%5B", "[", $this->url);
$this->url = str_replace("%5D", "]", $this->url);
```

Comment: Thanks steve-0.Its not worked.And also my PHP version is 5.2.6